# MVC - Changing or adding a class for either 'Html.ValidationMessage' or 'Html.TextBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

How do I change the class that is assigned to the control which is rendered by an MVC view by either the Html.TextBox or Html.ValidationMessage methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do something like this (not that you have to escape "class" with `@` because it's a reserved C# keyword):

```
Html.TextBox("Text", "Value", new { @class = "YourClassName" })
```

or if you don't like anonymous types:

```
Html.TextBox("Text", "Value", new Dictionary() { { "class", "YourClassName" } } )
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like you can. It's defined as readonly in HtmlHelpers.cs. You could, of course, change the css. Or, make your own helper that names it what you want.